# How to send requests from one app to another app?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a food ordering app and want to find out how to send orders to restaurants and delivery guys using a dashboard for the restaurants, and an application for a driver or rider etc. How can I go about it?

I want to create a food delivery service similar to Uber eats, which has 2 applications for the customers and drivers, a dashboard for the restaurants and a dashboard for the admin. Developing is not a problem, my query comes about as to how I can have information be sent between these platforms, including orders, and driver requests. Would I have to use something like fire base, if so how do I go about it?

I have used several videos and asked around for help but they haven’t come to a proper solution. Most of them do not show how information can be sent, or use complicated methods.

Comment: What your asking is quite broad, you need to narrow down your question.

Comment: I have edited the question. If it is not clear still please inform me.

Comment: You state development is not a problem yet don’t understand the fundamentals of network infrastructure. This question is way too broad and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use deeplink with specific structure

Append blew line manifest

Define ACTION_VIEW intent action so that the intent filter can be reached from Google Search

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

And add BROWSABLE category in order to be accessible from a out off app

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Add your link structure

```
<data android:host="order" android:pathPattern=".*" android:scheme="food"/>
```

Get data with intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

Send data to another app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("food://order"));
startActivity(launchIntent);
```